# Bounds for the norm of certain additive character sums

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, characters

Let $q$ be a power of a prime, let $\alpha$ be a primitive element in the finite field with $q$ elements and let $\chi$ be the canonical additive character of the field.
Recently I became interested in bounds for the norm of sums of the type
\begin{equation}
\sum_{d \mid N} \mu(d) \eta_k^{(d,q)} = \sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ \gcd(k,N) =1}}^{q-1}\chi\left(\alpha^k \right),
\end{equation}
where $N$ is a positive divisor of $q-1$, and $\eta_k^{(d,q)}$ is the $k$-th *Gaussian period* of type $(d,q)$ defined by
$$
\eta_k^{(d,q)} = \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{q-1}{d}} \chi\left( \alpha^{k + di}  \right).
$$
One could obtain bounds for these sums, say, by writing the Gaussian periods in terms of Gaussian sums $S(\psi)$, where the $\psi$ are multiplicative characters of the field, and then use the Triangle Inequality together with the fact that $|S(\psi)| = \sqrt{q}$ for non-trivial $\psi$. However I think these bounds would not be good as they do not account for all the possible changes in sign of the many terms in the sums. Another trivial bound is of course $\frac{q-1}{N}\phi(N)$, the number of terms in the right hand side above (since character images have norm $1$).
Could one do better than this last bound? Are there any bounds known in literature? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are occasions, where the bound for sums like $\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}\chi(\alpha^{Nk})$ that you get from the absolute value of Gauss' sums and triangle inequality is tight. I need to recall a few things and think a bit before I can tell whether they fit your sums as well.

Comment: For example if $N=\ell$ is a prime number, then I got (barring mistakes) that your sum, call it $S(N,q)$ can be written as
$$\ell S(q,\ell)+(\ell-1)=-\sum_{\psi, ord(\psi)=\ell}G(\psi).$$ 
Here $G(\psi)$ is a Gauss' sum and the summation ranges over the set of multiplicative characters $\psi$ of order $\ell$. Here it is IMHO that the occurring Gauss sums have either arguments very close to each other, or are even all equal.

Comment: (cont'd) If $q=p^n$, and $\ell$ happnes to be such a number that $p$ is a generator of the group $(\Bbb{Z}/\ell\Bbb{Z})^*$, i.e. $p$ is primitive modulo $\ell$, then the Gauss' sums are equal, because the Frobenius automorphism gives $G(\psi^p)=G(\psi)$, and all those characters are of the form $\psi^{p^j}$ for some $j$.

Comment: (cont'd 2) Also, even when $p$ is no primitive, the arguments of those Gauss' sums behave in the known way, when you extend the summation from $\Bbb{F}_q$ to its extensioin fields. An application of Kronecker density theorem then tells us that for some extension field $\Bbb{F}_Q$, $Q=q^m$, the arguments of the Gauss' sums are within $\varepsilon$ of each other no matter how small $\varepsilon>0$ is.

Comment: (cont'd 3) All this points in the direction that you should not expect a general bound better than what you get from triangle inequality and the result $|G(\psi)|=\sqrt q$. However, there may be interesting enough special cases, where you do get something better.

Comment: Thanks. With the triangle inequality one could get the upper bound $2^{\omega(N)}q^{1/2}$, where $\omega(N)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $N$. I tried a few examples and it seems not that bad. Although when the degree of the field extension is small (say < 5), the bound doesn't seem that good in general.. I wonder whether, in the special case that $N$ is such that each $\eta_k^{(d,q)} \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $d \mid N$, one could get better bounds? Thanks a lot again.